# How to fix an vtk DLL import error when compiling with Pyinstaller?

Tags: python, import, dll, pyinstaller, vtk

I'm having this error when I compile a code that uses the vtk module with pyinstaller.
[image]

usually I add some vtk hiddenimports to fix that kind of issue

```
a = Analysis(
['EEG_Viewer_Converter.py'],
pathex=[],
binaries=[],
datas=data,
hiddenimports=['vtkmodules','vtkmodules.vtkWebCore', 'vtkmodules.all', 'vtkmodules.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor', 'vtkmodules.util', 'vtkmodules.util', 'vtkmodules.numpy_interface', 'vtkmodules.numpy_interface.dataset_adapter',
```

in the .spec file generated with pyinstaller.
So I add `'vtkmodules.vtkWebCore'` in it but it didn't fix the issue this time.
How can I fix this issue when I execute the .exe?